# How to combine 2 3x3 matrices into a single matrice to find span and check whether is it linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I put
$$\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
2&0&0 \\ 
0&-1&0 \\
0&0&1
\end{matrix}\right]$$   and
$$\left[\begin{matrix} -2&0&0\\
0&-1&0\\
0&0&-1
\end{matrix}\right]$$

into a single matrix?

I'm trying to find the span and check whether is it linearly independent. I do understand to find both I need it to be in a single matrix but I'm a little confused on how to get started.

A little help would be much appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: whether what is linearly independent?

Comment: A basis for a vector space V is the set of vectors from V which:

1. spans V
2. is linearly independent

Comment: thank you, I had heard of what a basis was. Is your question whether that set of $6$ vectors in 3 dimensional space (2 of which are identical) is linearly independent?

Comment: The question is asking whether the set of matrices is a basis   in M3,3. If I'm not wrong, we have to check whether it spans M3,3 and whether it is linearly independent in M3,3? Do correct me if I'm wrong. but I'm not too sure where to start

Comment: right, so this is the ambiguity i was trying to clear up. You are in fact interested in the linear independence of the matrices

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\alpha\begin{bmatrix} 
2&0&0 \\ 
0&-1&0 \\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
+\beta\begin{bmatrix} -2&0&0\\
0&-1&0\\
0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
implies what about $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: α  and β would be 0?

Comment: @Jenny yes, and what does that tell you?

Comment: that both sets of matrices added together is = 0

Comment: ok, let me start here. What is the definition of linear independence?

Comment: the set of vectors cannot be written as a linear combination

Comment: can you complete that thought? I can take any vectors in the world and write a linear combination of them